# After being able to load the landing page(Home component) , how do you get the rest of the react components to render through github pages?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have been spending hours upon hours trying to get my create react app to deploy through git-hub pages.  I'm able to render the landing page/home component but the rest of my components won't render due to the change in paths once I click on a navigation link.  I have the right prod build in react and I am using HashRouter. Since my homepage loads and not the other nav/components I believe it is a simple route issue, but after all the documentation I've read I still can't solve the problem.  This is killing me lol. Here's a link to the homepage. Notice if you click on the nav links it gives an error. 
http://zonekid.github.io/TelevisionFavorites

For App.js

```
    `class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
<Container fluid>
    <Router basename="/">
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/twin-peaks" component={TwinPeaks}/>
    <Route path="/atlanta" component={Atlanta}/>
```

Nav component (HomeNav.js)

```
    <Nav className="justify-content-center" activeKey="/home">

        <Nav.Item>
            <Color1>
          <Nav.Link className="nav-link" href="/atlanta" eventKey="link-1">Atlanta</Nav.Link>
          </Color1>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
            <Color2>
          <Nav.Link href="/twin-peaks" eventKey="link-2">Twin Peaks</Nav.Link>
          </Color2>
        </Nav.Item>

`
```

Comment: Have you tried the links as `href="atlanta"` or as `href="./atlanta"`? The way they are now, they redirect the user to a URL outside your app

Comment: @TasosK. Thanks a billion!!! This got it running!!  Just added a #/atlanta instead of the ./atlanta.  Defintely did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If your app was made with `create-react-app`, you should set your `basename` to `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` instead of your current value of `/` like this:

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
```

Comment: Thanks a billion! This helped!